# How to play, stop and pause working on media player instance in android ?

Tags: java, android, audio, android-mediaplayer, playback

I want to develop media player type of application which has two button one for play and pause and one for stop. I take two image buttons in my layout file and reference it in Java file and code like this which I put here, but when I click on stop button audio is getting stopped but then I want replay audio file; but I cant play with play button.

my Java code below

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_aarti_fragment, container, false);

        btnplay=(ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.btnplay);
        btnstop=(ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.btnstop);
        seekbar=(SeekBar)v.findViewById(R.id.seekbar);

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.arti);
        btnstop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.stop();
                btnplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Stop",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        btnplay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(mp.isPlaying())
                {
                    mp.pause();
                    btnplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Pause",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                else
                {   btnplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_pause);
                    mp.start();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Play",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        return v;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This:

```
private BackgroundSound mBackgroundSound;
private MediaPlayer player;
public class BackgroundSound extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        player = MediaPlayer.create(HomePage.this, R.raw.background);
        AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)  getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
        float actualVolume = (float) audioManager
                .getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float maxVolume = (float) audioManager
                .getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        float volume = actualVolume / maxVolume;
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        player.setVolume(volume, volume);
        player.start();
        return null;
    }
}
```

For Playing:

```
        mBackgroundSound = new BackgroundSound();
        mBackgroundSound.execute();
```

For Stop:

```
        mBackgroundSound.cancel(true);
        if (player != null) {
             player.stop();
             player.release();
        }
```

For Pause:

```
        if (player != null) {
             player.pause();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Once a media player is stopped, you need to call prepare on it again to get it to a state where you can  call start().  Look at the state diagram here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#pause%28%29

Comment: my play and pause code is working nicely but when I press stop button it stop the audio but again when I want to replay this audio I cant play it again..

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help you....

```
//Click Listener on Image Button with play and Pause method

 PLAY.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Play-Pause();
        }
    });

//Play Pause method...........

 public void Play-Pause(){
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        PLAY.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);            
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    } else {
        PLAY.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, its better and simple solution !

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MediaPlayer mp;
    Switch sw;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.nokia);
        sw = findViewById(R.id.sw);
        sw.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                mp.setLooping(true);
            }
        });
    }
    public void play(View v){
        mp.start();
    }
    public void pause(View v){
        if(mp.isPlaying())
            mp.pause();
    }
    public void stop(View v){
        if(mp.isPlaying()) {
            boolean loop=mp.isLooping();
            mp.stop();
            mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nokia);
            mp.setLooping(loop);
        }
    }
}
```